# Wordpress - woocommerce - custom deals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

i probably should mention, i'm a rookie so please bear with me.

I'm making a food store for myself, using woocommerce, i am quite clear about everything else, except one thing, is that, 
how can i make custom deals like this food website has -> [website](https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-xpress-lu2/menu)
where user can select few options of their choice from multiple, or select their choice of drink etc etc

should i use API? or is there any other way?
Thanks in advance.